# Adding schedule to android application

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I want to create a scheduler for my app. My current idea is to create a background service which starts up on boot and listens to the date and time. This triggers my application. But I'm guessing this isn't the most efficient method. I googled quite extensively and didn't come up with anything different. Is there a more efficient way than creating a service?

**[EDIT]**

Making my question clearer. I'd like to make something like this.

Say I want to run the app every Monday at 10:00am how would I go about doing that? The method I concocted or something more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the system's [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) in conjunction with a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which starts an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

*Update:* On second read, what do you mean by *trigger my application*? I was assuming it's non-interactive, but if it is interactive, you could bring up your Activity with the help of the BroadcastReceiver; no IntentService required then. Saves you the time monitoring either way.

**Update** One of the central questions you have to ask yourself is, do I want to wake up the device, such that my {app, service} is run exactly at that point in time, or is it okay to have that run immediately after the device is woken up by the user, if "another Monday 10oo am" has passed by?

Regardless of the answer to that question, you'll use the system's AlarmManager to set up a repeating alarm, either with `setRepeating()` or `setInexactRepeating()`, and with either `RTC` or `RTC_WAKEUP`. `triggerAtMillis` is the time delta to the next Monday 10oo am and `intervalMillis` is the number of milliseconds which a week has.

And that's it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to fix the schedule of your code..
Try this code for schedule the particular functionality..

```
 Timer mTimer = new Timer();
    TimerTask mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /*your code here..*/
        }
    };
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask, getTomorrowMorning2AM(), 1000*60*60*24);

}
private static java.util.Date getTomorrowMorning2AM(){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.util.Date date2am =  c.getTime(); 
       date2am.setHours(2); 
       date2am.setMinutes(0); 

       return date2am;
  }
```

Comment: May I ask, in which Android Context would you create this TimerTask?

Comment: i created this timertask for function called once a day

Comment: This was not my question. My question was, in which Android Context are you creating it.

Comment: Are you told which activity is used that function?

Comment: Never mind. I just wanted to tell you in a friendly that your approach is either not working or wasting scarce resources or (most likely) both. Hence, it's not what one should do on an Android device. Good luck with your app.

Comment: this is not call any android context this is for java functionality. I this used my app for run the function one a day  that's it.

Comment: When you create a Timer, it creates a Thread object. On Android, all Threads are operating system level threads (pthreads), which means that you're wasting quite some resources for a once-a-day alarm. Another problem with your solution is that your TimerTaks holds a reference to your complete class, which probably holds a few other references; the reason is that you create it on-the-fly. This means that now there is a Timer thread in the system which keeps your Application and Activity object in memory all the time. As your customer, I wouldn't be amused.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation let me change timer functionality to  AlarmManager